# change caps lock as control in .bashrc but no use

Tags: keyboard-layout, bashrc

I want to make caps lock as control key, so I wrote this `setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier` to my bashrc file. The problem is that after I log in the next time or restart the system, nothing happened. Caps lock is still caps lock... So how to change caps lock to control key?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` commands just affects terminal session. You could assign this command to `~/.profile`or create a script with this command and add it to your [session startup programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Answer (score 1):

To make that change system wide and persistent, open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing, change the line

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc`script just change defaults at terminal session, and it doesn't extend to other areas of your environment. To make this, you could create a script file with this command in it, as:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier
```

Then you add it to your sesssion startup manager, as you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Answer (score 0):

I assigned the command to `~/.profile` and it works. Now I see that `~/.bashrc` script just change defaults at terminal session, people who are fresh to linux like me should notice this too. Thank you guys!